# How can I validate form and then execute additional code if successful

Tags: ajax, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I cannot figure out how to merge the following separate pieces of code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#signupForm").validate();
 });
```

and

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSignup").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/Newsletter/Signup",
            data: $('#signupForm').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $('#signupMessage').show(0);
                }
                else {
                    showValidationErrors(response.Data);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I need the first part to execute first, and if it validates the form successfully, then I need to exectute the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use [valid()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid).

Pseudo code;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#signupForm").validate();
    $("#btnSignup").click(function () {
        if ($("#signupForm").valid()) {
            // ajax query
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Does that work? I haven't checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat general way I use.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if (!$(e.target) && !$(e.target).valid()) {
        return;
    }
    // Ajax call here.
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",... });
});
```

Lastly, you could abstract the logic into an object for a more OOP approach

```
var formHandler = {
        onSubmit: function(e){
            if (!$(e.target) && !$(e.target).valid()) {
                return;
            }
            // Ajax call here.
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",... });
        }
}

$('form').submit(formHandler.onSubmit);
```